# Nothing happens when button is clicked in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I took all the code out for the post to save space. I am trying to get a form to work but noticed it wont submit so I took all the code out and checked on the button and found out that for some reason it wont work. I tried to log and toast messages but neither will work. I had a look at the log cat and no errors.

```
public class HomeFragmentNews extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homefragment_news, container, false);

        Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.btNewsSubmit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("hello", "Button click");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return v;
    }


}
```

XML

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btNewsSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add news"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.918" />
```

Comment: Working now Thanks @Onik

Comment: Could you please tell what was the problem?